# Double usage of scanf() depends on call order

Tags: c, input, scanf, ternary-search

I wrote a program in C which takes as an input a value and an ordered Array of integers and performs a ternary search to find the value(if it exists) inside the Array.

I have seen all the possible problems with the usage of scanf and the related topics here in Stackoverflow.

I have noticed that there is a difference if I call the 2 scanf functions in reverse order.

If I use the code as it is below. First read the value and after the array from the user, the program and scanf functions as expected.

```
printf("Enter the value to be searched in the Array: ");
int k;
scanf("  %d", &k);

printf("Type elements of A(sorted) separated by spaces (type 'end' to stop): ");

i = 0;  
while(scanf("%d", &A[i]) == 1) {
    i++;
}//while
```

Although if I use the scanf inputs in the reverse order the second scanf never stops to get user input and read values left in the buffer.

```
printf("Type elements of A(sorted) separated by spaces (type 'end' to stop): ");

i = 0;  
while(scanf("%d", &A[i]) == 1) {
    i++;
}//while

printf("Enter the value to be searched in the Array: ");
int k;
scanf("  %d", &k);
```

I cannot understand what is the difference in the calling order.
I have tried the solutions mentioned in the other threads but none worked.

Just as a reference here is the whole code(working as expected):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


int ternarySearch(int A[], int l, int r, int k){
int i;
int first,second;

if(l>r){
    return -1;
}

i= (r - l)/3;

if(i==0){
    i++;
}

first = i+l-1;
second = i*2+l-1;

if(A[first]==k){
    return first;
}
else if(A[first]>k){
    ternarySearch(A, l, first-1, k);
}
else
 {
    if(A[second]==k)
      return second;
    else
    if(A[second]>k)
       ternarySearch(A, first+1,second-1, k);
    else
       ternarySearch(A, second+1,r, k);
 }
}


int main(){
const int maxarraylen = 1000;
int i;
int n;
int A[maxarraylen];
char string[250];

printf("Enter the value to be searched in the Array: ");
int k;
scanf("  %d", &k);

printf("Type elements of A(sorted) separated by spaces (type 'end' to stop): ");

i = 0;  
while(scanf("%d", &A[i]) == 1) {
    i++;
}//while
n=i-1;


//We assume the array is sorted otherwise we can use any sorting algorithm e.g. code from task1

scanf("  %d", &k);






int result;
result=ternarySearch(A, 0, n, k);

if(result==-1){
    printf("The value was not found in the Array.\n");
}
else{
    printf("The value was found in position no. %d.\n", result);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should indent your code and make use of decent variable names to aid understanding.

Comment: Complete code is only used as a reference if anyone wants to run the program. The only 2 important lines relevant to the question is `scanf("  %d", &k);` and `scanf("%d", &A[i]) == 1`. One read only one integer variable and the other reads several integers from the command line.

Comment: So scanf removes the carriage return'\r' and/or new line character'\n'? Is this why the one way works but the other does not? Can you please explain how **%*s** works?

Comment: For what it's worth, there is no difference between the scanf formats `"%d"`, `" %d"` and `"  %d"`. Whitespace in the format string matches zero or more whitespace characters; the `%d` format starts by skipping zero or more whitespace characters.

Comment: xing, rici thank you for the helpful information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not 'stepping over' your `end` input.

We can see this by doing an experiment using the following program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(void) {
    FILE *f;
    long f_pos;
    int ret;
    int i;
    int data[5];
    int data_last;
    int search;

    f = fopen("./input.txt", "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        perror("fopen()");
        return;
    }

    /* read in the values for the array */
    data_last = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ret = fscanf(f, "%d", &(data[i]));
        printf("fscanf(data[%d]): ret: %d\n", i, ret);
        f_pos = ftell(f);
        printf("ftell(): %ld\n", f_pos);
        if (ret != 1) {
            break;
        }
        data_last = i;
    }

    /* check that we read in at least one value */
    if (data_last == -1) {
        printf("no input data!\n");
        return;
    }

    /* insert 'fix' here */

    /* pre-load the 'search' with known garbage */
    search = 987;

    /* now read in the search value */
    ret = fscanf(f, "%d", &search);
    printf("fscanf(search): ret: %d\n", ret);
    f_pos = ftell(f);
    printf("ftell(): %ld\n", f_pos);

    /* print out our info */
    for (i = 0; i <= data_last; i++) {
        printf("data[%d]: %d\n", i, data[i]);
    }
    printf("search for: %d\n", search);

    return;
}
```

With the following data in `input.txt`:

```
123
456
end
456
```

The output is as follows:

```
fscanf(data[0]): ret: 1
ftell(): 3
fscanf(data[1]): ret: 1
ftell(): 7
fscanf(data[2]): ret: 0
ftell(): 8
fscanf(search): ret: 0
ftell(): 8
data[0]: 123
data[1]: 456
search for: 987
```

`ftell()` tells us where the file's cursor is, and in this case we can see that it is at byte 8... the `e` of the input line `end`.

It doesn't get past it, and thus the next attempt to read a number (`%d`) will fail too!

It's also a good idea to check the return values! We can see that the `fscanf(&search)` call has failed to read a number!

---

The solution is to insert this snippet just after we check that we recieved array values:

```c
/* this is the 'fix' */
ret = fscanf(f, "end");
printf("fscanf(end): ret: %d\n", ret);
f_pos = ftell(f);
printf("ftell(): %ld\n", f_pos);
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed and informative answer!